# Creating a TIFFDictionary for an image file

Tags: python, macos, core-graphics

I'm trying to add a TIFF Dictionary to an image file in OS X. 
[From Apple's documentation,](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/cgimageproperties/format_specific_dictionaries) it looks like `kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary` defines a dictionary, which then has keys like `kCGImagePropertyTIFFXResolution` inside it.

I can't see how to implement that in my python code. At the moment, I've just got the dictionary as a key alongside the other keys. (And so it doesn't set any of the keys into the file.) 
Here's my code:

```
options = {
    kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary: 'TIFFDictionary',
    kCGImagePropertyTIFFXResolution: "300",
    kCGImagePropertyTIFFYResolution: "300",
    kCGImagePropertyTIFFResolutionUnit: 2
    }   
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image, options)
CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, options)
```

Here's some other python code from an [open source script](https://opensource.apple.com/source/efax/efax-38/efax/imagestopdf.auto.html), which presumably works, but I can't understand what it's doing.

```
imageProps = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSrc, 0, None)
        if imageProps is not None :
            tiffProps = imageProps[kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary]
            if tiffProps is not None :
                xRes = tiffProps[kCGImagePropertyTIFFXResolution]
                yRes = tiffProps[kCGImagePropertyTIFFYResolution]
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that nested dictionaries ARE needed. The other problem was that the numbers need to be numbers, unsurprisingly.

```
options = {
    kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary: {
        kCGImagePropertyTIFFXResolution: 300,
        kCGImagePropertyTIFFYResolution: 300,
        kCGImagePropertyTIFFResolutionUnit: 2
    }
}
```

And an even better solution is not to use a TIFF dictionary at all, so it will work with other file formats:

```
        options = {
            kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight: 300,
            kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth: 300
            }
```